# Removing all .csv files except the latest file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'm trying to remove the files in a directory called `Date_Sources`. This directory has 5 subfolders in it, called `Test1` `Test2` ... `Test5`.

I know how to remove the files every 90 days :

```
find /home/deployer/Data_Sources/.../..   -mtime +90 -type f -exec rm -r '{}' \;
```

How can I make sure my script will remove all the files after 90 days *EXCEPT the newest file* (Per each subdirectory)?

So the script has to go to `Date_Sources/Test1`, `Data_sources/Test2`, ..., etc. and make sure all the files are removed after 90 days except the newest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
find /home/deployer/Data_Sources -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d > afile
while IFS= read -r subdir
do
  find "$subdir" -mtime +90 -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" \
      | sort \
      | head -n-1 \
      | sed 's|[[:blank:]]\+| |' \
      | cut -f 2 -d " " > bfile
  while IFS= read -r each
  do
    rm -vf "$each"
  done < bfile
done < afile
rm -f bfile afile
```

Explanation:

find all directories in `/home/deployer/Data_Sources` within the immediate directory (`-maxdepth 1`) and excluding itself (`-mindepth 1`), and dump this to a file called `afile`

```
find /home/deployer/Data_Sources -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d > afile
```

Read each line from `afile` and store in environment variable `subdir` (See the `done` line of this loop to see that `afile` is being piped to the `while` loop)

```
while IFS= read -r subdir
do
```

Run a `find` command on each `subdir`, listing only files older than 90 days (and print the timestamp with the file)

```
  find "$subdir" -mtime +90 -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" \
```

`sort` the output of the `find`

```
      | sort \
```

grab all but the last line of the `sort` output (the last line is the newest file)

```
      | head -n-1 \
```

replace all multiple whitespaces to a single space

```
      | sed 's|[[:blank:]]\+| |' \
```

grab the second column from the output, defining space as delimiter; all dumped to a file called `bfile`.  (Could probably use a tab as a delimiter somehow and not use the `sed` above, but I wasn't sure how to specify it so it would work; `-d "\t"` certainly didn't do the trick)

```
      | cut -f 2 -d " " > bfile
```

Now, read `bfile` line-by-line and store in `each` environment variable (Again: See the done line to show `bfile` being piped in)

```
  while IFS= read -r each
  do
```

Actually do the removal of the old files (being verbose and suppressing prompts)

```
    rm -vf "$each"
  done < bfile
done < afile
```

Remove the temporary files `bfile` and `afile`

```
rm -f bfile afile
```

Note:

-Updated to remove use of `for` loops to properly handle special characters and spaces in paths; also double quotes on variables (as suggested by @mklement0)

Comment: Thanks ! I just wanna make sure, I'm on a right path, can you do this with sub folders.
I mean how to specify the subfolders here because there are 5 .
Can it just be /Data_Sources and that's it ? for example :
    for each in $(find /home/deployer/Data_Sources/ -mtime +90 -type f -printf "%T+\t%p\n" \
I'm not sure what will come after Data_sources.
thanks again

Comment: @Rohamsk:  I think I have what you were requesting now.

Comment: Also, if you have other files in these folders you don't want to delete, you might want to add `-name "Test*"` to the first find command and `-name "*.csv"` to the second find command.

Comment: @Rohamsk:  Please upvote and accept if it works for you, or let me know if there's still a problem.

Comment: Please [do not use `for` to parse command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and double-quote variable references.

Comment: @mklement0:  `for` is fine in this case as long as there are no spaces in the paths.  `find` will not return wildcards or blank lines.

Comment: @ryry1985: (a) the constraint regarding spaces deserves a big caveat in you answer; (b) `find` returns whatever the filename is, and it will be _interpreted as a glob by the shell_, due to using an _unquoted_ command substitution passed to `for` (hint: quoting won't help). The bottom line is: do not use `for` to parse command output, as the link suggests, and as the linked article explains.

Comment: @mklement0:  Can you have * ! () $ in filenames?

Comment: @ryry1985: Yes. Try `touch '*!()$'`.

Comment: @ryry1985 sure I will test it and let you know soon. thanks

Comment: @mklement0:  Updated my answer per your suggestion.  Please remove your downvote if you are fine with it.  I need all the rep I can get.

Comment: @ryry1985 Man ! you are awesome. It worked perfectly fine ! 

I wish you could briefly explain to me how the syntax worked. That would help me a lot to learn it too. Much appreciated.  Thanks a ton !

Comment: @Rohamsk:  Now added some notation to my answer

Comment: @ryry1985 thanks very much ! I appreciate all your help !